# C++ Building on CentOS 7 & Running on 6.5

Tags: c++11, centos

I've written a program which uses a lot of the new features in C++11. I wrote it on MacOS X, it compiles and runs fine with Apple Clang, Boost 1.5* and libc++ (assumption, as opposed to libstdc++). The program is for personal use and it won't need to be deployed on more than a few servers.

I shipped the production server to its overseas location with CentOS 6.5 installed. So I built a dev server with CentOS 6.5 installed. Pushed my code up to the dev server, used the package manager to get everything I thought I needed and then tried to compile - only to be bitterly disappointed.

Problem: I think the Clang version from EPEL is fine. However it wasn't playing nice with libstdc++ provided by the base repo - CentOS 6.5 is only up to GCC ~4.4. For example, I couldn't get GTest to compile. So I searched around and found a repo called the devtoolset-2 which had GCC ~4.8. It was made clear that this repo should only be used for testing purposes. Using the libstdc++ from this worked much better. However, now I was having a few boost problems - as the base CentOS 6.5 repo is only up to ~1.44. I've been trying to get 1.55 installed but failing... tried from repos and building myself but I'm guessing other dependencies are still out of date - e.g. Binutils. Either way it had all been a big mess.

I think moving the dev server to CentOS 7 would make things much easier. However, it is not going to be easy to move my production server over.

Basically I'm looking for advice. Can I build on CentOS 7 and copy the required libraries over to the production server? And what are the potential pitfalls of this? Should I statically link everything - including libstdc++? Or are there any other suggestions - apart from moving the production server to CentOS 7 (which I'll *try* do if I absolutely need to).

If you think this is not a 'stackoverflow' question please let me know.

Thanks.

John.